# Adding rails apps to nginx avoiding high load time on 1st access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to automate the deployment of multiple rails applications in one server with nginx + passenger. I have one server block for each application...

My problem is that everytime that I insert a new rails application to nginx I need to reload the config file and every rails application is reloaded. The reload with passenger takes a while because passenger loads all rails app to memory in first access...

I want to avoid this load time but i really don't know how.

- Is possible to load only 1 server with nginx? Or should I have 1 nginx instance for each rails app (don't know if this is possible)?
- Should I use other ruby app server? Probably thin would be faster on 1st load...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicorn sounds like it might be a better fit for your deployment scenario. You can keep nginx up front, but instead of loading rails itself, it will just connect to a unicorn Unix socket. Further, you can reload your application with new code gracefully, while nginx stays up and Unicorn swaps out backend quietly.

Comment: I've used nginx + unicorn and it fits my deployment scenario. Now I can manage each instance individually with 0 downtime. Thanks